# WindowsIdentity Class not shown in System.Security.Principal Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I want to get the username of the user using the application. So i want to use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentUser() . Refer [How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c)

But the problem  is the System.Security.Principal namespace does not give me any such class. In fact the namespace shows only the two interface and no classes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Principal(v=vs.110).aspx

I tried it on a server machine and on a local machine. Doesnt work.

Since that did not work i tried Environment.username. But Visual Studia cant find the property either. I opened the metadata file but no such property exists.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Environment(v=vs.100).aspx.

What am i doing wrong? FYI i'm working on a .net 4 silverlight application.

AfterThought: Is this because of silverlight?

Comment: I look at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Principal(v=vs.110).aspx page and I see WindowsIdentity class in the package

Comment: @DmitriyFinozhenok Switch that page to Silverlight instead of .NET 4.5 and you will see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight 4 Get Current User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470926/silverlight-4-get-current-user)

Comment: @nvoigt, its a web application so cant be WPF. I think the link u have given will work. Let me try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is a browser based framework. Reading the current operating system user is not possible. If you need to communicate with the users Desktop that way, write a normal WPF application for Windows Desktop.